# Как отправить и обработать неопределенное кол-во text-input в POST?

Tags: php, массивы

я новичок, сильно не пинайте.

Вывожу из БД через while неопределенное кол-во строк с id,

для каждой такой строки создается 4 input.  3шт для заполнения + 1 скрытый с текущим id внутри.

Не могу понять, как правильно через массив отправлять в POST для последующей обработки этих значений через foreach?

$row[4] это ID

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs1)){
...
     <input type="text" name="offer[<?php print $row[4];?>]" value='0'>
    <input  type=text name="offer[]" value="<?php print $row[3];?>"/>
    <input  type=text name="offer[]" />
    <input  type=text name="offer[]" value="<?php print $row[4]; ?>" hidden=hidden />
    }
```

соответственно это выводит значения абсолютно неверно.

```
if (!empty($_POST['offer'])){
        foreach ($_POST['offer'] as $item) {
        print $item[0]." - ".$item[1]." - ".$item[2]." - ".$item[3]."<Br>";
        }
}
```

П.С. решение:

```
foreach ((array_chunk($_POST['offer'],4)) as $item) {
```

Comment: `неопределенное кол-во text-input` и `создается 4 input` - чему верить?

Comment: хорошо, неопределенное кол-во строк, в каждой строке по 4 input

Comment: То есть 4 поля ввода - это столбцы в таблице БД, вы делаете выборку и для каждой `$row` нужно вывести 4 поля ввода (`input`) на страницу. Одно из четырех - скрытое от заполнения пользователем?

Comment: нет, упрощу описание: таблица товар(ид, ид_заявки). делаю запрос к этой таблице, где ид_заявки=мое значение.  результат запроса вывожу через while ,в этом while так же создаю 3 input для заполнения под каждый вывод, 4й input это ид_заявки.  Нужно будет заполнить эти input пользователю, чтобы я дальше отправил через POST результат в таблицу предложения (ид, ид_заявки, ид_товара, input-1, input-2,input-3

Comment: Думаю в сторону того, что нужно результат из POST вместо foreach обрабатывать через цикл с шагом в 4 ?  Но как :)

Comment: Вы бы добавили в вопрос структуру таблицы в БД и `sql` запрос, чтобы большей аудитории стало понятно. Это всего две строки текста.

Comment: вопрос решил, помогло foreach ((array_chunk($_POST['offer'],4)) as $item). а кода там много, т.к. связано по 3-4 таблицы в запросах, и куча ненужно информации. хотел на пальцах попроще вопрос задать

Comment: На пальцах и я могу объяснить `<input  type=text name="offer[$id][input-1]" />` )))

Answer (score 0):

Как мне кажется, ваша ошибка в том, что вы не используете имена полей таблицы (или не таблицы, не суть). Когда вы сделали выборку из базы вам нужно получить ассоциативные массивы для строк, вы же, судя по всему, получаете обычные индексированные. Отсюда попытка запихать все данные в один длинный массив и дальнейшее разбиение его на части по 4 значения. Обычно при изменении структуры таблицы такой подход заканчивается долгим и нудным поиском ошибок, вызванных изменением индексов и соответствующих им полей.

сначала получите данные в виде ассоциативного массива (`->fetchAll('assoc')` или `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`), так чтобы результат был массив элементов вида (условно):

```
 [
    ['id' => ..., 
     'product_id' => ...., 
     'title' => ....
    ],
    ......
 ]
```

Затем при выводе вам создавайте разметку следующего вида

```
 <input type="hidden" name="offers[0][id]" value="..."/>
 <input type="hidden" name="offers[0][product_id]" ... />
 <input type="text"   name="offers[0][title]" ... />

 <input type="hidden" name="offers[1][id]" value="..."/>
 .....
```

При отправке такого запроса на сервер, вы будете получать соответствующий массив.

Comment: я все же сделал по своему и забыл про это мучение :)  Нет, из таблицы я получаю запросом грубо говоря только неопределенное кол-во строк с ID и к каждому ид  рисуется 3 интупа для ввода, Идею я вашу понял, и даже пытался реализовать до создания поста тут, но не понял как обработать POST, если делать 3 инпута вида name="offers[0][имя]. Тут наверное как раз было бы правильно делать name="offers[ид_из_базы][имя инпут]. а принимать в POST как правильно?

Comment: @Виктор дак вы сделайте `print_r($_POST)` да посмотрите в каком виде приходит. а `offers[$id]` не прокатит